# I'm following Codecademy rails turorial and stuck in using bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I'm sorry for my poor English. English is not my first language.

I almost finish rails tutorial in codecademy. Portfolio is the last project of this tutorial. I can't use bootstrap in this project. Here is the task.

> Set up the layout file (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb). The layout file lets you build a base view that contains all the common elements of your site, such as CSS files, the header, and the footer. The <%= yield %> defines the portion of the layout that child templates can fill in.
>
> 1. In the  below the , add CSS for the Roboto web font. Follow the instructions here. Choose the styles Thin 100, Light 300, Medium 500, and Bold 700.
> 2. Add CSS for Bootstrap. Follow the instructions here. Use the latest compiled and minified CSS, and not the optional theme.
> 3. Make sure both CSS URLs start with https.

This is the link of css for bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn

I just tried to insert link tag in the page,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But I failed. I think I have to do something more. Would you please tell me how to do it? Thanks advanced.

Comment: maybe you forgot to add the font? it should be added separately

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a css file into your app's header

you need use the following codes

```
stylesheet_link_tag "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

you can read more here : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: You're right. I should study 'Make a website' lecture first. Because I'm not good at using CSS. Anyway thanks.